# Getting error on windows but not on linux with japanese characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, windows-console

I want to read files names from a directory and print out their names.
This is my code:

```
png_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('output'):
    for file in files:
        png_files.append(file)
for name in png_files:
    print(name)
```

This works but only on linux (not on windows)and I dont know why. My files have some Japanese characters and I know that the problem is in them but dont know how to fix.

I am getting this message:

> 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 19-27: character maps to <undefined>

I have tried `encode('UTF-8')`and then I get :

> b'forecast_traffic\xe4\xb8'

I know that when you have `b''` it means it is a bytestring so i tried `name.encode('UTF-8').decode()` but i again get the same error message and if I try just encode i get the error :

> 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Does anybody know how to fix this and where my mistake is?

Comment: The windows console cannot handle special characters. I've has the same issue before with spanish characters.

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera Thank you so much, i lost an hour thinking what can the problem be. You can post it as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera It was fixed. Check my answer. Hope It will work with Spanish too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Windows console doesn't print Unicode" bug was fixed. Check the link below. http://bugs.python.org/issue1602
and this https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

OR install win_unicode_console using `pip install  win-unicode-console`

Comment: So I undersstand that in python 3.6 this is fixed, right?